# Multi-Friend-Selector - Facebook and post to wall

Tags: facebook

Been reading here for quite a while now.. But cant seem to figure out Facebook. 
I certainly am not a coder, allways been more of a practical guy and learned as i go but.. this stuff i really cant figure out..

I'm making a fanpage applicaton - like a quiz or something.. Been using developers.facebook samples and arranging stuff on my own but .. cant get it to work..

What am i doing?
1. I would like to embedd a Multi-Friend-Selector in a fanpage as a "iframe" or allways visual or a popup. 
Now i solved it by adding an input button that calls multi-friend-selector but when i choose friends to send an application request they dont get it? I've been trying for quite some time now but cant seem to make it work..

1. Want to post to wall at the same time when users use my app.. Solved it with a button click that calls out a dialog to post to wall but could i embedd it with a "send" button or something?

Here's my code;

"MFS;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<p>
<input type="button"
  onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
  value="Invite Friends To Grobnik"
/>
</p>

<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '338625489510276',
    redirect_uri : 'http://www.facebook.com/TrackDay',
  });

  function sendRequestToRecipients() {
    var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'test',
      to: user_ids, 
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'test'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
  }
</script>
```

"

But dont know.. am i suppose to add some permisions to my app settings? It's really bugging me that Inviter show's up but doesnt send out requests for the application

Thanks for all the help.. Really appreciate it and i'm really trying to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<button id="send-to-many">Send App request</button>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '338625489510276',
  });
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about the Platform.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response) {
alert('invited');
    } else {
alert('not invited');
    }
  }
);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I know i'm learning about the platform :) .. It works exactly like my code up.. Show's the inviter and returns a positive response but none of the friends get the app request? Thanks for helping me..

Comment: weird.. I tried exactly the same code and i get a positive respond (popup) but invitation is nowhere to be seen.. Tried with multiple friends.. Strange.. Could my app settings be wrong?

Comment: oh one more thing did you installed your app? i think you need to install it at first

Comment: i added it as a page tab.. on a fanpage profile.. or timeline as it is now .. Should i try installing it?

Comment: just checked.. Shows it as an installed app in "Applications" at facebook edit page..

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Grobnik-Track-Day/169351487901?sk=app_338625489510276

Comment: Not loading it as a canvas URL just a page tab so it can be added to a fanpage - else the url is http://apps.facebook.com/trackdayinfo
but it will report that app is broken cause it's not using any canvas URL..

Comment: well thats right , i wasn't able to do so too (exactly your problem)
but i have another recommend install another app use api code of it & try that

Comment: i'l try it a little bit later.. Should i try with canvas URL? i think i can add the pagetab no matter the canvas url... I'm gonna have to do it anyhow since timeline kicked in now.. Will report back in a few hours cause my workload is crazy right now .. thanks for the help! appreciate it..